# Может ли быть комбинированная связь между таблицами БД?

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

Есть класс `Appointment`(Встреча):

```
class Appointment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Visitors { get; set; }
}
```

Он связан с классом `User` по типу многие-ко-многим (пользователи, которые идут на встречу) и, одновременно, связан с тем же классом `User` по типу один-к-одному (создатель встречи). Может ли быть такая комбинированная связь? Или правильнее будет убрать поле `Author`, а автора поместить в коллекцию `Visitors` как первый элемент?

Comment: Конечно может быть, проблема то в чем?

Comment: @Monk Да в общем-то уже ни в чем) Просто я нигде не встречал комбинированных связей, вот и думал, не будет ли это ошибкой.

Comment: Вот как раз помещение в коллекцию первым элементом и будет ошибкой - коллекции в EF не сохраняют порядка элементов.

Comment: Проблемы нет, но я бы сделал отдельный класс, которые связывал бы Встречи и Пользователей. У Встречи свои атрибуты (в том числе и автор) и Пользователей свои. А связь "многие-ко-многим" реализовать через промежуточный класс. По нему можно было бы легко находить и участников конкретной встречи, и для конкретного Пользователя легко найти все его встречи. В нем же можно контролировать, например, то чтобы Пользователь не был участником двух встреч в один момент времени.